# Data connection between InfoPath and SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath, infopath-data-connections

I am a newbie at using InfoPath and SharePoint! But I am a fast learner and help is DEFINITELY appreciated at this moment, given my time crunch.

I have published my InfoPath form to my SharePoint library. 
In my form, I currently have:

- a dropdown list of current concert events entered in the library
- a fieldname [StartDate]
- a fieldname [EndDate]
- a fieldname [City]
- a fieldname [State]

  ** for each row in the SP library there will be columns: Event name, startdate, enddate, city, and state

**QUESTION**
I have already made a data connection on the dropdown list to the library.
WHAT I WANT: is once the user fills out the city and state, the dropdownlist will automatically populate all the concert events related to the designated city and state.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new rule to state field.

Condition - check if city is filled

Action - set a field's value. Select the dropdown and set it's value from the data connection.